# Removing Duplicate object from array in jquery code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my array in jquery , which contains duplicate objects/elements :

```
[{
    "name": "hello",
    "label": "world"
}, {
    "name": "abc",
    "label": "xyz"
}, {
    "name": "hello",
    "label": "world"
}]
```

I am using the following piece of code to remove duplicate elements but it not working the duplicate elements are not removed.

```
var result = [];

$.each(subservices, function (i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1)
        result.push(e);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: hi there please add jsfiddle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Function `$.inArray` works fine for simple types (e.g. number or string), but for complex types it does not produce the correct result, because it tries to match by reference. Instead of using `inArray` in your loop you can search the array using function `grep`:

```
var subservices = [{
        "name": "hello",
        "label": "world"
    }, {
        "name": "abc",
        "label": "xyz"
    }, {
        "name": "hello",
        "label": "world"
    }
];

var result = [];
$.each(subservices, function (i, e) {
    var matchingItems = $.grep(result, function (item) {
       return item.name === e.name && item.label === e.label;
    });
    if (matchingItems.length === 0){
        result.push(e);
    }
});

//displays result [{"name":"hello","label":"world"},{"name":"abc","label":"xyz"}]
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/defujjhp/)

Answer (score 4):

You need to filter array by unique name/value. Here is some pure JS solution:

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "hello",
    "label": "world"
}, {
    "name": "abc",
    "label": "xyz"
}, {
    "name": "hello",
    "label": "world"
}];

var result = data.filter(function(el, i, x) {
    return x.some(function(obj, j) {
        return obj.name === el.name && (x = j);
    }) && i == x;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: This will break if there is no duplicate in data, eg:
var data = [{
    "name": "abc",
    "label": "xyz"
}, {
    "name": "hello",
    "label": "world"
}];
for this it will return only 1 object
http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/f1qb7xjc/

Comment: @user3501613 This code I wrote 3 years ago just sucks. Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/fvLhx1o3/

Comment: thanks @dfsq, i think this findIndex won't work in IE and all,thats why i preferred grep,please give me any solution instead of findIndex

Answer (score 1):

This is because these two objects are distinct, even though all the attributes inside are the same. You can see this from:

```
console.log(result[0] === result[2]);
```

which results in false.

Instead, you need to iterate through your array based on a unique identifier, such as name & label as such:

```
for(var i = 0, i < results.length; i++) {
    if (result[i].name === ... && result[i].label === ...) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

to check if your item is unique.